# Is there a security problem with using Thymeleaf?

Tags: ajax, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am using Springboot and thymleaf to create an administrator website.

In the user page, I can see information such as users' email addresses and phone numbers.

I am now showing data read from DB into html using thymeleaf.

Then someone told me that there is a security risk if I bring information such as an email address or phone number to Thymeleaf. So I have to use Ajax to bring it.

Is this true?

Comment: No that's not true.

Comment: Can you explain it to me if possible?

Comment: What do you mean? Using thymeleaf to display the values is no more a security risk than using AJAX.

Comment: I'm sorry I couldn't explain it properly. He said that when looking at the page source, Ajax does not display the contents, but Thymeleaf displays the contents. I am not sure if that is a problem.

Comment: If the phone number is visible on the page, then regardless of how it is acquired it will be in the page source.